# Where do I find a test http server for simulating timeouts and error codes

Tags: java, apache, http, browser

I am thinking that this would be an Apache server with some custom pages, or possibly a java application.  Used for browser or http client testing, it should give me a variety of 500 errors when a specific page is requested.  Give me a page that responds in 5 seconds, 10, 30 or whatever.  Give me a page where the first byte does not come back for 30 seconds.  Give me a page where I get a few bytes per second.

I expect that others have made this kind of thing before, and I know it is not too difficult, but I would certainly like to use what someone else has already made.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) for this sort of thing. When using the quickstart functionality, if you edit the script file you run it from, it will automatically restart.

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly working in the Java world, so jumping into Python is not ideal.  Here are a few alternatives based on Java:

- FitNesse - fitnesse.org
- Jetty - www.mortbay.org/jetty/
- Java HTTP Server (Sun) - java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/

I was not aware of the sun httpserver, but this seems to provide the lightweight implementation that I can add a small amount of code to for simulating timeouts and error responses.